# Help - Enabling ASP.NET for IIS7 on Vista is failing

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, windows-vista

I am actually not able to install any windows feature through the "Turn Windows features on or off" dialog.  I am trying to get ASP.NET working for IIS7 on Vista Ultimate.

I also tried running aspnet_iisreg -i but got an unspecified error.

I checked several places and none of the solutions worked.  They mostly had to do with duplicate mime types in applicationhosts.config (which there are none).

Anyone know how to fix this problem?

Ryan

Comment: What happens when you try to install?  Also just as a warning, most likely this question will get closed.

Comment: Give us more info, log files showing the warning (was there an error number etc).

Answer (score 1):

Try running `SFC /scannow` from a command prompt, and then examine the log at `%windir%\logs\cbs\cbs.log` to see if it made any repairs to the .net framework (which is considered a system component in vista).

-Oisin